# Running function over all possible combinations

Tags: r, algorithm, function, combinations

I have a conceptual question regarding a function I am trying to create.

I wish to create a sort of network diagram. In order to do this I must look at 6 tables and compare the tables to each other, in twos. The connection will be based on one variable that every possible combination, of these couple of tables, may share.

Lets call this Variable, x.

If table1$x1 = table2$x3, for example, Id want to put the variable x1 (for table1), in a third table. With only the shared variable between the two tables in one column and, a second column stating that this variable is shared between table1 & table2.

I want this comparison to occur throughout every possible combination of entries within the tables. Therefore, Id have to compare:

1&2, 1&3, 1&4, 1&5, 1&6

2&3, 2&4, 2&5, 2&6,

3&4, 3&5, 3&6,

4&5, 4&6,

5&6,

where each number represents a table number.

Where the output in the end will be a single table stating all the shared variables between one table and another, as well as which two tables share this variable.

Thank you all for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example where `f(c(i, j))` computes a function of `tables[[i]]` and `tables[[j]]`, `nms` is a vector of pair names and the last line computes `f` for each pair.

```
tables <- lapply(1:6, "*", BOD) # list of 6 tables used as input
f <- function(ix) { 
  tab1 <- tables[[ix[1]]]
  tab2 <- tables[[ix[2]]]
  sum(abs(tab1 - tab2))
}
nms <- combn(seq_along(tables), 2, paste, collapse = "-")
setNames(combn(seq_along(tables), 2, f), nms)
```

giving:

```
1-2 1-3 1-4 1-5 1-6 2-3 2-4 2-5 2-6 3-4 3-5 3-6 4-5 4-6 5-6 
111 222 333 444 555 111 222 333 444 111 222 333 111 222 111
```

Comment: This helped alot. Thank you!